# xuggler icontainer read from inputstream

Tags: java, xuggler

I am using xuggler to transcode videos into different formats.
If I open my IContainer directly from a file, it works perfectly, however, this time I want to open IContainer use an InputStream. Strange thing is I tried to open a mp4 format video via FileInputStream, the IContainer can be opened using this FileInputStream, but I cannot read Ipacket in this stream. Can someone give me some suggestions? Did miss something? I really need my xuggler to deal with streams

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //the file input stream
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("test.mp4");

    //icontainer format
    IContainerFormat format = IContainerFormat.make();
    format.setInputFormat("mp4");

    IContainer container = IContainer.make();
    //open container via FileInputStream
    int data = container.open(fi, format);

    IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
    //read packet 
    int info = container.readNextPacket(packet);

    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(info);
}
```

results

```
data: 0
info: -1094995529
```

According to IError, an unknown error here when I tried to read a packet. I'm using xuggler 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, streams must be seekable(like FSDataInputStream in hadoop), otherwise Xuggler cannot handle it, FileInputStream is not such kind of stream, sad.... Actually, seek() function is important for Xuggler to read a media file

Now, to work on seekable stream.

I have found solution, Xuggler actually can handle streams via [IURLPROTOCOLHANDLER](http://www.xuggle.com/public/documentation/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/io/IURLProtocolHandler.html), I created my custom class which implements iurlprotocolhandler and it "works".
I learned from this [Example](https://github.com/openpreserve/video-batch/blob/master/src/main/java/at/ac/ait/dme/video_batch/xuggle/HDFSProtocolHandler.java), which use stream FSDataInputStream.